# how to install driver for atheros ar8161 in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, networking, atheros

I am completely new in using ubuntu, studying painful and trying to find a way. most discussions are for ubuntu 12.10, so what packages should I install for this driver if I use 11.10?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `system settings` > `Aditional drivers`. This is a utility that helps you find available open source drivers for your installed hardware. This may help.